# How to access global scope from cloudinary react widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, cloudinary

So I am having a trouble at figuring it out on how to access global scope from cloudinary react widget function, what i want to is to set state on response.

Function

```
uploadWidget() {
  cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'descl4zie', upload_preset: 'g3d6k0nl', tags:['xmas']},
    function(error, result) {
      console.log(result);
      this.setState({photo: secure_url});
    });
 }
```

Render

```
render() {
  return (
    <button onClick={this.uploadWidget.bind(this)} className="upload-button">
      Add Image
    </button>
  )
}
```

Currently getting this error:
Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: I think you should bind(this) for openUploadWidget function

Answer (score 1):

The callback function given to `openUploadWidget` is not bound to `this`, so `this` will not be what you expect inside of it.

You could e.g. use an arrow function instead to use the enclosing lexical scope which has the `this` value you want:

```
uploadWidget() {
  cloudinary.openUploadWidget(
    { cloud_name: "descl4zie", upload_preset: "g3d6k0nl", tags: ["xmas"] },
    (error, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.setState({ photo: result });
    }
  );
}
```